# What happens when a string literal is passed to a function accepting a const std::string & in C++?

Tags: c++, stdstring

as you can probably guess from the title, I want to understand what exactly happens when a std::string is passed to a function as a const reference, because earlier today I ran into a few situations I didn't quite understand entirely. Here's some code:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Interface {
    virtual void String1(const std::string &s) = 0;
    virtual void String2(const std::string &s) = 0;
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
};

struct SomeClass : public Interface {
    void String1(const std::string &s) override { s1 = s.c_str(); }
    void String2(const std::string &s) override { s2 = s.c_str(); }
    void DoSomething() override { printf("%s - %s\n", s1, s2); }

private:
    const char *s1, *s2;
};

struct AnotherClass {
    AnotherClass(Interface *interface) : interface(interface) {
        this->interface->String1("Mean string literal");
    }

    void DoTheThing() {
        std::string s("Friendlich string literal");
        interface->String2(s);
        interface->DoSomething();
    }

private:
    Interface *interface = nullptr;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    SomeClass some_class;
    AnotherClass another_class(&some_class);

    another_class.DoTheThing();
}
```

When using const char * for s1 and s2 in SomeClass the program prints **Friendlich string literal - Friendlich string literal** or **[some rubbish] - Friendlich string literal** instead of **Mean string literal - Friendlich string literal** as I was expecting.

When switching to std::string for s1 and s2 it works as expected, printing **Mean string literal - Friendlich string literal**.

What a coworker and I are guessing is that the string in the ctor of AnotherClass goes out of scope but SomeClass still has the address of the string stored because of c_str().

When using std::string instead of const char * for s1 and s2 it actually makes a copy, so going out of scope isn't a problem. Like this:

```
struct SomeClass : public Interface {
    void String1(const std::string &s) override { s1 = s; }
    void String2(const std::string &s) override { s2 = s; }
    void DoSomething() override { printf("%s - %s\n", s1.c_str(), s2.c_str()); }

private:
    std::string s1, s2;
};
```

So... what's really happening? Why doesn't it work with const char *? Why does it work with std::string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass a string literal to a function that accepts `const std::string&`, the following events occur:

- The string literal is converted to `const char*`
- A temporary `std::string` object is created. Its internal buffer is allocated, and initialized by copying the data from the `const char*` until the terminating null is seen. The parameter refers to this temporary object.
- The function body runs.
- Assuming the function returns normally, the temporary object is destroyed at some unspecified point between when the function returns and the end of the calling expression.

If the `c_str()` pointer is saved from the parameter, it becomes a dangling pointer after the temporary object is destroyed since it points into the temporary object's internal buffer.

A similar problem will occur if the function accepts `std::string`. The `std::string` object will be created when the function is called and destroyed when the function returns or soon afterward, so any saved `c_str()` pointer will become dangling.

If the function accepts `const std::string&` and the argument has type `std::string`, however, no new object is created when the function is called. The reference refers to the existing object. The `c_str()` pointer will remain valid until the original `std::string` object is destroyed.

Comment: And what happens to the const char * that's created from the string literal?

Comment: @Marco The pointer itself is also a temporary object, which is destroyed at the end of the full-expression. This doesn't matter, unless you intend to keep a pointer or a reference to the pointer itself. It's like how we normally don't worry about the lifetime of `3` in the expression `2 + 3`.

Comment: So... if I would change the parameter to const char * it will keep it until it's not needed anymore by SomeClass?

Comment: @Marco If you change the parameter to `const char*`, then that pointer value will point to the string literal. The string literal will live until the program terminates. Therefore, it is safe to make a copy of that pointer and dereference it later. However, saving a pointer to the pointer parameter itself would not be safe, since the pointer parameter would be destroyed after the function returns.

Answer (score 1):

A `char *` isn't an object, it's a pointer to characters that exist in some other context.  If you assign such a pointer to a temporary variable, or data contained within a temporary variable, it will be invalid when the temporary is destroyed.  Using it after that point produces undefined behavior.

When you have member variables of `std::string`, a copy is made at the time of assignment so it doesn't matter if the temporary is destroyed or not.

Comment: Why does it copy though? Because the type of the member variable is std::string? But isn't the argument a reference?

Comment: @Marco a `std::string` always contains its own character data, so if it accepts a reference it still makes its own copy.

Comment: Thank you very much :)